# Function CreateDC For Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: function, vb6

I searched all over the internet to get a detailed explanation of how to use the **CreateDc** function in VB 6.0, But there are only examples and source Codes ...

Can anyone please explain to me ... what and how this function works ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a copy of the excellent book "[The Visual Basic 6 Programmer's Guide to the Win 32 API" by Dan Appleman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672315904). Now out of print, but you can pick it up [secondhand](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672315904) very cheaply.

It provides an invaluable explanation of Win32 graphics API calls *in the context of VB6*, which is rather specialised. You need to cooperate with the VB6 runtime if you are to call these functions successfully.

Answer (score 3):

CreateDC is not a VB6 function per se, but rather a part of the Windows API.
You can get a detailed description of the function on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183490(v=VS.85).aspx.

The description goes something like this:
The CreateDC function creates a device context (DC) for a device using the specified name.

To use it in VB6 you need to add the declaration of the function and the DEVMODE structure to your code.  You will find these in Add-Ins->API Viewer in VB6.

Comment: http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/CreateDC.shtml is also a good reference, look @ the linked examples.